# Couldn't restore frame crash in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

I currently have an application that has four QNetworkAccessManagers being called at four different times on recurring timers. When it is time to post/read again with the manager I call:

Example:

```
reply = manager#->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(URL)));
```

Timers expire every:

```
Manager1 - 10s
Manager2 - 15s
Manager3 - 90s
Manager4 - 300s
```

This works just fine. However, after many days of this running, after I recieve a reply from 1 of the 4 I get

```
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `QDynamicMetaObjectData' value
    found `QXmlUtils::isPublicID(QString const&)' instead
Couldn't restore frame #2 in current thread, at reparsed frame #0
Couldn't restore frame #2 in current thread, at reparsed frame #0
```

or just

```
Couldn't restore frame #1 in current thread, at reparsed frame #0
Couldn't restore frame #1 in current thread, at reparsed frame #0
Couldn't restore frame #1 in current thread, at reparsed frame #0
Couldn't restore frame #1 in current thread, at reparsed frame #0
```

and then the program crashes. My question is: Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: This has nothing to do with th qt-creator tag.

Comment: Except that it happens in QT-Creator, my mistake.

Comment: can you update the question then, please if it works in console, but not in QtCreator? By the way, it is Qt, not QT. The latter means Quick Time which is a different project. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Such an error would normally come from `gdb`.

Since you insist that you're not running it under the debugger, then another possibility is that you're corrupting memory somewhere, perhaps ELF tables or type information data or such.

Run it under `valgrind` and see if you get errors. My bet is that you'll find it quickly.

Comment: The only reason I am is because if crashes after a few days as a standalone as well.

Comment: Of does it need to be a release standalone?

Comment: Again: you're running it under gdb. That message is produced by gdb. How are you starting your executable?

Comment: Using a terminal I cd to Program-build-desktop-Debug. I then type ./ProgramName